# Maven missing class ValueSource

Tags: java, macos, maven

I'm trying to run the Vadiin addressbook tutorial but when i run this `mvn jetty:run` I get this error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project addressbook: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources: org/codehaus/plexus/interpolation/ValueSource
```

I'm using OS X Yosemite and i've installed maven using brew.

Comment: Which maven version? Furthermore checked if during the build warnings have been occured?

Answer (score 1):

I solved removing the .m2 folder and running again `mvn jetty:run`!